# Is there a way to automatically save Pages documents copies as PDF on every save?

Tags: macos, pdf, pages, automation, iwork

Is there a way to enable Pages (version 10.1 (6913)) to automatically save a copy of the current document as PDF every time I save it to avoid a manual export?

Comment: I’ve added macOS tag. Please update if yours using a different platform of pages 10.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use Folder Actions to trigger an AppleScript that creates the  PDF whenever the contents of the folder are changed. The problem may be the fact that the document is still open.

But realistically, you don't have to manually press Save in Pages anyway, so just assign a key command to Export to PDF. You could even use Command S.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't. The only way to save a Pages document as a PDF while in Pages is to export the Pages Document as a PDF. There may be some online converter but those will only work after you have saved the Pages document.

Answer (score 0):

I would perhaps think of using Automator
Each time a file get's saved ... this link as a few ideas but the person is trying to sell stuff

https://www.ghostotter.com/using-automator-convert-pages-pdf/